# https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-app.js in ./node_modules/firebase/firebase-messaging.js not found

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

Code :-

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```js
//firebase-messaging-sw.js

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-app.js");
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-messaging.js");

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I am getting an error that :-

```
This dependency was not found:

* https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-app.js in ./node_modules/firebase/firebase-messaging.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-app.js
```

I cannot install `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-app.js`. My firebase version is `"firebase": "9.6.3"`. I am building a Firebase Push Notification System in my vue app.